# Add an ongoing listing number to a SQL table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a simple car listing site where a form is filled out with things such as make, model, year, etc. of a car and then upon submission, this information is added to cars database as one particular listing with a listing ID number. To make this easy, I thought of simply assigning the first listing as 1 and then just adding 1 to this for each additional listing. My question is how would I go about writing the code for something like this? Is there a way to use some type of if statement that assigns the ID to 1 each time and if the ID exists, `ID=i+1` or is there an easier way of doing this? I am later going to use this listing number as a way of displaying the most recently listed cars on a sidebar (probably by just using a `sum(listingID)` type of query).

Comment: Why not just have an auto increment field in your table and then just pull the value when you need it? Start at something like 6000 and then increment by one everytime you add a car.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still really inexperienced with SQL. So to do this, would I just use something like create table listings(L_ID int auto_increment, make varchar(255), etc.); or is there some other way to do what you are saying. Thanks a lot for the quick response!

Comment: Which fields you want in your table?

Comment: I am trying to get Listing_ID, make, model, year, condition, asking_price, description. I want these to all be linked to the Listing_ID and then have that auto-incremented. Is there a limit to the amount of field on table can have because I am getting an error.

Comment: you try that in mysql or sql server?

Comment: I am using mysql and just tried this query with no luck... 
CREATE TABLE listings
(
L_ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
make varchar(55) NOT NULL,
model varchar(55) NOT NULL,
year int NOT NULL,
condition varchar(25),
asking_price int,
description varchar(500),
PRIMARY KEY (L_ID)
)
;

Comment: WOW, I am dumb.. Didn't realize that I was trying to use the word condition as a field name and I can't do that. I have created the table, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use `AUTO_INCREMENT` in `ID` field

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a primary key for that table, and then set the field as identity, check this for reference: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp